# Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have a very peculiar problem:(not using web.config)

```
DefaultFacebookApplication dfa=new DefaultFacebookApplication();
dfa.AppId = "..."; dfa.AppSecret = "...";
var fbWebContext = new FacebookWebContext(dfa);
```

Then i use the normal example in .aspx file. (init...). Even though i get the cookie in the request(which has all fields), FacebookWebContext still fails to find the access_token(& others).

The sample projects works fine. Where would the problem be?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you try this.

```
FacebookApplication.SetApplication(dfa);
```